Rutas relativas y absolutas en php y los estilos
Estoy trabajando en una web en PHP y aún me está quedando difícil de entender el tema de las rutas absolutas y relativas de los estilos y el js ya que me funcionan en un solo nivel de profundidad, más no en todos.
Tengo esta estructura de archivos:
example.com/
 ├─ [app]
 │   ├─ [controlador]
 │   │   └─ [logistica]
 │   │       └─ index.php
 │   ├─ [vista]
 │   │   ├─ [logistica]
 │   │   │   └─ index.php
 │   │   └─ [plantilla]
 │   │       ├─ navbar.php
 │   │       └─ footer.php
 │   └─ [modelo]
 │       └─ [logistica]
 │           └─ index.php
 ├─ [assets]
 │   ├─ [css]
 │   ├─ [js]
 │   └─ [imagenes]
 ├─ [logistica]
 │   └─ index.php  
 └─ index.php


app/vista/plantilla/navbar.php contiene los import de estilos css y los scripts js.
logistica/index.php hace include a app/controlador/logistica/index.php
app/controlador/logistica/index.php tiene el include a app/vista/logistica/index.php, app/modelo/logistica/index.php y app/vista/plantilla/navbar.php

Cuando yo ingreso al sitio web (example.com/index.php), los estilos funcionan correctamente en toda la página, incluso los enlaces en la navbar. El problema ocurre cuando ingreso a example.com/logistica, pues carga logistica/index.php, pero no se cargan los estilos de la página. Entonces yo puse a corregir los estilos para que funcionaran dentro del segundo nivel, pero ahora ya no funcionan en el primer nivel. Entonces la solución debe funcionar en cualquier nivel de la web.
Quisiera obtener sugerencias sobre como solucionar este problema, ya que es necesaria esta estructura de archivos para mantener el orden.
He revisado otras respuestas, pero aún no logro entender, ya que han sido ejemplos distintos.
De antemano, muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Sin poder ver el HTML en cuestión y basandome en lo descrito, todo apunta a que el path a los recursos es relativo y no absoluto, por lo que la solución podría ser tan simple como indicar el path absoluto. Ej: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/styles.css"/>

Todos los imports que empezaban con ../../ y asi sucesivamente, los reemplace y ahora todos empeizan por /        asumiendo que todos estan desde la raiz, por ejemplo:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> ahora es <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
Y funciona en todo lado.
Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!!

el problema es si la raiz cambia ... espero que no pase
